# Problem with a relative positioned input element in a flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Goal:** The middle DIV (MIDDLE) within a flexbox row should be centred.

**Problem:** Right element contains a relative positioned input element. As a result, the middle DIV element (MIDDLE) is no longer centred but shifted to the left.

I had tried to change the positioning to absolute. Then it would be correctly centred but the input field can no longer be moved out.

```js
const btnS = document.querySelector('.bg-search');  
let isOpen = false;
btnS.addEventListener('click', (e) => {  
  const searchBox = document.querySelector('.searchbox');
  const inputBox = document.querySelector('.searchbox-input');

  console.log(e.target, isOpen)
  if (isOpen === false) {
    searchBox.classList.add('searchbox-open');
    inputBox.focus();    
    isOpen = true;    
  } else {   
    console.log('close input')
    searchBox.classList.remove('searchbox-open');
    inputBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusout'));
    isOpen = false;
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
  --nav-height: 50px;
}
nav {
  height: var(--nav-height);
  z-index:13;
  background: green;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap:10px;
  z-index: 20;
  position: relative;
}
.body {
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  dispyay: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100vh;
}

.searchbox {
  position:relative;
  min-width:50px;
  width:0%;
  height:50px;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;    
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.searchbox-input {
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  background:#dcddd8;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0px 55px 0px 20px;
  font-size:20px;
  color: #000;
}
.searchbox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-open{
  width:100%;
}

.searchbox-icon,
.searchbox-submit {
  width: var(--nav-height);
  height: var(--nav-height);
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:22px;
  right:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#dcddd8;
  background:#172b3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">


  <nav>    
    <div class="container bm-btn">
      LEFT
    </div>      
    <div>MIDDLE!!</div>
    
    <div>
      <form class="searchbox bg-search">
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp(this);" required>
          <input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" value="GO">
          <!--button-- class="searchbox-icon">S</button-->
          <span class="searchbox-icon">S</span>
      </form>      
    </div>
  </nav>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the attributes on the parent `.searchbox` needed to be on the `.searchbox-input` child instead. Rather than changing the width of the parent, I moved the animation over to the child. I made the `.searchbox-input` positioned absolutely, so that when it changes width, it will not affect the flow of the elements in the flexbox. Please take a look and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```js
const btnS = document.querySelector('.bg-search');  
let isOpen = false;
btnS.addEventListener('click', (e) => {  
  const searchBox = document.querySelector('.searchbox');
  const inputBox = document.querySelector('.searchbox-input');

  console.log(e.target, isOpen)
  if (isOpen === false) {
    searchBox.classList.add('searchbox-open');
    inputBox.focus();    
    isOpen = true;    
  } else {   
    console.log('close input')
    searchBox.classList.remove('searchbox-open');
    inputBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusout'));
    isOpen = false;
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
  --nav-height: 50px;
}
nav {
  height: var(--nav-height);
  z-index:13;
  background: green;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap:10px;
  z-index: 20;
  position: relative;
}

.body {
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  dispyay: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100vh;
}

.searchbox {
  position:relative;
  min-width:50px;
  height:50px;    
}

.searchbox-input {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  background:#dcddd8;
  width:0%;
  height:50px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-size:20px;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
.searchbox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.searchbox-open .searchbox-input {
  width:15em;
}

.searchbox-icon,
.searchbox-submit {
  width: var(--nav-height);
  height: var(--nav-height);
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:22px;
  right:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#dcddd8;
  background:#172b3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">


  <nav>    
    <div class="container bm-btn">
      LEFT
    </div>      
    <div>MIDDLE!!</div>
    
    <div>
      <form class="searchbox bg-search">
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp(this);" required>
          <input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" value="GO">
          <!--button-- class="searchbox-icon">S</button-->
          <span class="searchbox-icon">S</span>
      </form>      
    </div>
  </nav>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hello colleague! Thank you very much for your answer. And it works. I had to take some time to look at what exactly you changed. It took me a while to see that you added this line: `.searchbox-open .searchbox-input {
  width:15em;
}` then it worked. Thanks a lot and have a nice evening! BTW: If you know a better solution for sliding the input box back and forth I would be very grateful.

Comment: @MaxPattern You're welcome, and the current method of sliding the input box back and forth seems fine to me. Was there something you disliked about it?